# How to align braces of a column in a diagram

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ]
\Bigg\{ \text{Lorem Ipsum} \Bigg\} \arrow[rr, "\text{dolor sit amet...}"'] \arrow[dd, "\text{sed ligula porttitor...}"']                                        &  & \Bigg\{ \text{Consectetur adipiscing elit} \Bigg\} \arrow[dd, "\text{eros eu dictum...}"]        \\
                                                                                                                                                                   &  &                                                                                                 \\
\Bigg\{ \text{Praesent pretium purus} \Bigg\} \arrow[rr, "\text{velit in porttitor...}", dashed]                                                       &  & \Bigg\{ \text{Class aptent taciti} \Bigg\}                                        \\
                                                                                                                                                                   &  &                                                                                                 \\
\Bigg\{ \text{Nam facilisis} \Bigg\} \arrow[uu, "\text{accumsan porttitor...}"] \arrow[rr, "\text{fringilla mi sed...}", dashed] &  & \Bigg\{ \text{Mauris ligula} \Bigg\} \arrow[uu, "\text{nec velit massa...}"', dashed]
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

I would like the braces of each node on the diagram to be aligned (so that the horizontal arrows are aligned), and if possible, allow for (center-aligned) multi-line text inside the braces. How can I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? (Observe that automatic line breaking is enabled in the 'boxes' inside the curly braces.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text macro
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Consectetur adipiscing} % desired width of 'box'
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox{\mylen}{\centering #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd} %[]
\Biggl\{ \mybox{Lorem Ipsum} \Biggr\} 
\arrow[rr, "\text{dolor sit amet...}"'] 
\arrow[dd, "\text{sed ligula porttitor...}"']
&  & 
\Biggl\{ \mybox{Consectetur adipiscing elit} \Biggr\} 
\arrow[dd, "\text{eros eu dictum...}"] 
\\
&  &  \\
\Biggl\{ \mybox{Praesent pretium purus} \Biggr\} 
\arrow[rr, "\text{velit in portti...}", dashed]  
&  & 
\Biggl\{ \mybox{Class aptent taciti} \Biggr\}  \\
&  &   \\
\Biggl\{ \mybox{Nam facilisis} \Biggr\} 
\arrow[uu, "\text{accumsan porttitor...}"] 
\arrow[rr, "\text{fringilla mi sed...}", dashed]
&  & 
\Biggl\{ \mybox{Mauris ligula} \Biggr\} 
\arrow[uu, "\text{nec velit massa...}"', dashed]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Totally new to tikz, so I don't even known how to find this stuff on my own yet. Thank you!

Comment: @Feryll - Strictly speaking,, the `\mybox` macro and `\mylen` length parameter are ordinary LaTeX constructs, and thus aren't related to tikz *per se* .

Comment: Yeah, but the \parbox, and just the notion of achieving the alignment through uniformly sized text boxes rather than vertical guides like in Illustrator or some such, was lost on me without your help.